# II don't want my code to stop when decoding a field I'm decoding is empty

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct WatchProvider: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let link: String?
    let rent: [WatchProviderDetails]?
    let buy: [WatchProviderDetails]?
    let flatrate: [WatchProviderDetails]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case link
        case rent
        case buy
        case flatrate
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        link = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .link)
        rent = try container.decode([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .rent)
        buy = try container.decode([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .buy)
        flatrate = try container.decode([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .buy)
    }
}
```

So I'm getting data from api and decoding it into this struct. Thing is sometimes rent would be empty, other times, flatrate would be empty, etc.. Problem is though, everytime any field is empty

> sink error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "rent", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "US", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "rent", intValue: nil) ("rent").", underlyingError: nil))

Any help how can I overcome that error, or better ignore it when it isn't there?

Comment: Either declare rent as optional or set a default value after a try? on rent decoding

Comment: In your `init(from decoder: Decoder) {...}`
you could try using `flatrate = try container.decodeIfPresent([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .flatrate)`
 note also the `forKey: .flatrate` not `forKey: .buy` and use `decodeIfPresent` for all properties.

Comment: Didn't I already declare rent as an optional by adding ? after [] above?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t saw it in the not indented part. Use try? when decoding optionals .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to delete `init(from decoder:)`

If a struct member is declared as optional it remains `nil` if the corresponding key is missing

```
struct WatchProvider: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let link: String?
    let rent: [WatchProviderDetails]?
    let buy: [WatchProviderDetails]?
    let flatrate: [WatchProviderDetails]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case link, rent, buy, flatrate
    }
}
```

`decodeIfPresent` is useful if the struct member is non-optional and you want to assign a default value if the key is missing for example

```
struct WatchProvider: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id = UUID()
    let link: String
    let rent: [WatchProviderDetails]
    let buy: [WatchProviderDetails]
    let flatrate: [WatchProviderDetails]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case link, rent, buy, flatrate
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        link = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .link) ?? ""
        rent = try container.decodeIfPresent([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .rent) ?? []
        buy = try container.decodeIfPresent([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .buy) ?? []
        flatrate = try container.decodeIfPresent([WatchProviderDetails].self, forKey: .flatrate) ?? []
    }
    
}
```